# grep not functioning when in a function

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a master list, `master.csv`, that looks like:

```
line1
line2
bill, 1
sonia, 2
rhonda, 3
patty, 4
```

and a roster file that I'd like to filter by:

```
bill
rhonda
```

I want to preserve the headers of `master.txt`, so I do `head -n 2 master.csv >out.csv && grep -f roster.txt master.txt >>out.csv` and I get:

```
line1
line2
bill, 1
rhonda, 3
```

This is great, but I have to do it all the time, so I wrap it in a function:

```
filterSections(){
    head -n 2 /dev/stdin && grep -f $1 /dev/stdin
}
```

So, in theory, I can do `filterSections roster.txt <master.csv >out.csv`,
but I only get:

```
line1
line2
```

On my larger files, it seems to be missing only the first line. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should work but you should avoid putting large amount of data on stdin. You can use this single `awk` command to get same output:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]; next} FNR <= 2 || $1 in seen' roster.txt master.csv
```

```
line1
line2
bill, 1
rhonda, 3
```

To put this in a function:

```
filterSections() {
    awk -F, 'FNR == NR { seen[$1]; next } FNR <= 2 || $1 in seen' "$1" "$2"
}
```

Call it as:

```
filterSections roster.txt master.csv
```

**awk explanation:**

- `-F,`: Make comma as input delimiter
- `FNR == NR`: For the first file in input i.e. `roster.txt`
- `{ seen[$1]; next }`: Store `$1` (1st column) in associative array `seen` and move to next record in same file
- `FNR <= 2`: When 2nd file's record no is `<= 2`
- `||`: or
- `$1 in seen`: 1st column from 2nd file is found in associative array `seen`

**References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: This works, though I've never used awk before, so I'm not really sure how. Could you elaborate a bit on what says?

Comment: I have added explanation and some useful `awk` references.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `head` is reading a large chunk of data, and then only writing 2 lines.  By the time `grep` tries to read from the file descriptor, there's no data left.  This is a well known problem, and the shell built-in `read` is designed to handle it:

```
filterSections(){
    read line  # Read all characters up to first newline, and no more
    echo "$line"
    read line  # Read the 2nd line, and no more
    echo "$line"
    grep -f "$1"
}
```

Note that `read` and `grep` read from stdin by default, so there's no need to specify `/dev/stdin`

Comment: This really helps my understanding of what's going on. I spend comparatively little time writing in bash, so these little idiosyncrasies are often hard for me to root out.